# If C isn't object oriented, then C is _____ oriented?

Tags: c

What type of programming is C. It is not object oriented, but what oriented is it? I googled it, and got no good answers.

Comment: It might be worth noting that programming paradigms are not always called _____ oriented. Edit: A quick look at [Wikipedia's article on programming paradigms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm) suggests that paradigms named _____ oriented are a plurality, but not a majority. It is also worth noting that most paradigms on the list are not popular/"successful".

Answer (score 6):

**tl;dr**: C supports the Programming Paradigm *Imperative Programming* which is composed of the Programming Concepts *record*, *procedure*, and *state*. As an abstraction mechanism, C can encode *Abstract Data Types* using Separate Compilation and Opaque Pointer Types.

There are about 34 principal Programming Paradigms, as identified by Peter van Roy and Seif Haridi:

- active object programming / object-capability programming
- ADT functional programming
- ADT imperative programming
- concurrent constraint programming
- concurrent object-oriented programming / shared-state concurrent programming
- constraint (logic) programming
- continuation programming
- descriptive declarative programming
- deterministic logic programming
- event-loop programming
- first-oder functional programming
- functional programming
- functional reactive programming (FRP) / weak synchronous programming
- imperative programming
- imperative search programming
- lazy concurrent constraint programming
- lazy dataflow programming / lazy declarative concurrent programming
- lazy functional programming
- monotonic dataflow programming / declarative concurrent programming
- multi-agent dataflow programming
- multi-agent programming / message-passing concurrent programming
- nonmonotonic dataflow programming / concurrent logic programming
- relational & logic programming
- sequential object-oriented programming / stateful functional programming
- software-transactional memory (STM)
- strong synchronous programming

Programming Paradigms, in turn, are composed of Programming Concepts, and Peter van Roy and Seif Haridi have identified 18 of those:

- by-need synchronization
- cell (state)
- closure
- continuation
- instantaneous computation
- local cell (private state)
- log
- name (unforgeable constant)
- nondeterministic choice
- port (channel)
- procedure
- record
- search
- single assignment
- solver
- synchronization on partial termination
- thread
- unification (equality)

If you want to understand more about Programming Paradigms, Peter van Roy made [this amazing poster that shows the 34 major paradigms and their relations and positions on various axis](http://WWW.Info.UCL.Ac.Be/~pvr/paradigms). He also wrote the article [*Programming Paradigms for Dummies: What Every Programmer Should Know*](http://WWW.Info.UCL.Ac.Be/~pvr/VanRoyChapter), which is targeted at musicians, and thus very approachable. And if you want the *full* treatment, [*Concepts, Techniques, and Models of Computer Programming* by Peter Van Roy and Seif Haridi](http://WWW.Info.UCL.Ac.Be/~pvr/book) is the definitive book on Programming Paradigms.

If we look at the poster and start at the very top, we can try and follow the arrows to see where we end with C.

The very first concept at the top is *record*. C does support records (called `struct`s). So, let's look at what arrows we can follow. There is only one, and the new concept is *procedure*, which C also supports (called *functions*).

From this node in the graph, there are two arrows with the concepts *closure* and *cell (state)*. C does not support closures, but it does support state. So, we end up at the Programming Paradigm *Imperative Programming*. From here, we have another possible two arrows, labeled *search* and again *closure*. C doesn't support either, so we are at the end.

And if you look at the node for *Imperative Programming*, you will note that C is actually mentioned as an example for this paradigm together with Pascal.

So, there you have it: C implements the *Imperative Programming* Paradigm, which is composed of the *record*, *procedure*, and *state* concepts.

C is also sometimes said to support *Procedural Programming* because the primary method of abstraction, the primary unit of decomposition, the primary unit of behavior, the primary method of structuring your program (which also means the primary method of structuring your *thoughts*) is the *Procedure*.

Personally, I don't really like this classification, because in my opinion such an important entity should be first-class but procedures are not first-class in C. (Other people would argue that *function pointers* make procedures first-class in C.)

There is another important difference between Imperative Programming in C and Object-Oriented Programming, and that is the way that *Data Abstraction* is performed.

In Object-Oriented Programming, the mechanism for Data Abstraction is (not surprisingly) Object-Oriented Data Abstraction. This essentially refers to the *Message Protocol*, the internal representation of an object is hidden behind the Behavioral Interface (aka Protocol) formed by the Messages it understands and how it responds to those Messages.

In C, the mechanism for Data Abstraction is (typically) *Abstract Data Types*. With Abstract Data Types, the Abstraction is formed by the Type System. (C does not *directly* support Abstract Data Types, but they can easily be encoded using Separate Compilation and Opaque Pointer Types.)

One of the major differences between Object-Oriented Data Abstraction and Abstract Data Types is that two instances of the same Abstract Data Types have access to each other's internal representation, whereas an Object can *never* access another Object's internal representation *even if they are of the same type*.

A great explanation of this difference is given in [*On Understanding Data Abstraction, Revisited*](http://CS.UTexas.Edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf) by [William R. Cook](http://WCook.BlogSpot.Com/), which is *very* approachable.

Comment: nice answer, pity the question is so downvoted :(

Comment: @Ewan: it is not a pity that the question is downvoted. It is a pity the question is written so badly and shows so few research that it is actually not very astonishing it gets downvotes.

Comment: Would it be worth editing the question to make it, at least, a bit more "worthy" of the answer?

Answer (score 2):

C is a procedurally-oriented language (not the greatest of terms, but it works). Code and data are viewed as separate entities - code is organized into a collection of *procedures* (functions) that operate on separate data items.

C++ is object-oriented.  Code and data are organized into a collection of *objects* that can both encapsulate and manipulate data.

Both C and C++ are *imperative* languages - program state is manipulated by executing sequences of statements.

Answer (score 0):

First line of the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) on C,

> C (/siː/, as in the letter c) is a general-purpose, **procedural** computer programming language supporting structured programming, lexical variable scope, and recursion, while a static type system prevents unintended operations.